# Match parts of string that are not consecutive stretches of certain character

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a simple function that yields all stretches of at least gapSize consecutive N's from a string:

```
def get_gap_coordinates(sequence, gapSize=25):
    gapPattern = "N{"+str(gapSize)+",}"
    p = re.compile(gapPattern)
    m = p.finditer(sequence)
    for gap in m:
        start,stop = gap.span()
        yield(start,stop)
```

Now I'd like to have a function that does the exact opposite: Match all characters that are NOT consecutive stretches of at least gapSize N's. These stretches may occur at any position in the string (beginning, middle and end) with any given number.

I have looked into lookarounds and tried

```
(?!N{25,}).*
```

but this does not do what I need.
Any help is much appreciated!

edit:
For example: a sequence NNNNNNACTGACGTNNNACTGACNNNNN with should match ACTGACGTNNNACTGAC for gapSize=5 and ACTGACGT & ACTGAC for gapSize = 3.

Comment: Can you post a sample phrase with the characters that you are trying to match?

Comment: Please do not put your question's tags into your title. You have the tag section for that.

Comment: Yes. It's not phrases but DNA- sequences. for example in: `NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNACTGTAGTGANNNNNACGTGTGTGTGTG`  i would like to match `ACGTGTGTGTGTG` and `ACGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTAC`. however, the N's may be anywhere

Comment: So you basically want to match any group that does not have an N?

Comment: @lfk: If the gapSize is 10, then what is the output for your example?

Comment: @kaz: no, i want to match any group that is not at least gapSize N's

Comment: @kaz, sorry, i just realized i messed up the example above. for the given example my expected output would be `ACTGTAGTGANNNNNACGTGTGTGTGTG`. With a gapSize of 5 it would be ACGTGTGTGTGTG and ACGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTAC

Comment: @nhahtdh: for a gapSize of 10 it would be `ACTGTAGTGANNNNNACGTGTGTGTGTG`

Comment: @lfk: Please edit those examples into the question. As for the solution, you can split the input with `N{<gapSize>,}`.

Comment: @nhahtdh These are many very large (totaling over multiple GB) strings, and I just need the coordinates, so if possible I would like to avoid splitting them

Comment: @lfk: Use the same regex and manage the index on your own then. I don't think there is a simple solution to match directly.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like python lookahead/behind only has support for fixed length matches.  The issue is that you need to lookahead/behind for a varying length of "N" (10 to infinity).

Comment: I repeat @nhahtdh - Please put the examples into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative lookahead seems to work ok. E.g. for gap-size 3, the regexp would be:

```
N{3,}?([^N](?:(?!N{3,}?).)*)
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/zO8yI0/1).

```
import re

def get_gap_coordinates(sequence, gapSize=25):
    gapPattern = "N{%s,}?([^N](?:(?!N{%s,}?).)*)" % (gapSize, gapSize)
    p = re.compile(gapPattern)
    m = p.finditer(sequence)
    for gap in m:
        start,stop = gap.start(1), gap.end(1)
        yield(start,stop)


for x in get_gap_coordinates('NNNNNNACTGACGTNNNACTGACNNNNN', 3):
    print x
```

Warning: This might not match well at the beginning of the string, if the string does not start with an 'N' sequence. But you can always pad the string with gap-size times 'N' from the left.

Comment: Thanks, something like this is what I was looking for! Can you think of any way to deal with initial N's other then padding?

Comment: I think this one does the job (example for gap-size 3): `((?:^N{0,2})?[^N](?<!N{3})(?:(?!N{3}?).)*)`  The generic case is:
`((?:^N{0,%s})?[^N](?<!N{%s})(?:(?!N{%s}?).)*) %(gapSize - 1, gapSize, gapSize)`  In this case, the beginning of the string is handled explicitly with the first non-caputring group, then there is one negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a *pure* regex solution which seems to be what you want, but I wonder if there is actually a better way to do it.  I'll add alternatives as I come up with them. I used several online regex tools as well as playing around in the shell.

[One of the tools](https://www.debuggex.com) has a nice graphic of the regex and facilty to generate SO answer *code*: the regex (with a gap of 10) is:

```
^.*?(?=N{10})|(?<=N{10})[^N].*?(?=N{10})|(?<=N{10})[^N].*?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Usage:

```
s = 'NAANANNNNNNNNNNBBBBNNNCCNNNNNNNNNNDDDDN'
def foo(s, gapSize = 25):
    '''yields non-gap items (re.match objects) in s or
       if gaps are not present raises StopIteration immediately
    '''
    # beginning of string and followed by a 'gap' OR
    # preceded a 'gap' and followed by a 'gap' OR
    # preceded a 'gap' and followed by end of string
    pattern = r'^.*?(?=N{{{}}})|(?<=N{{{}}})[^N].*?(?=N{{{}}})|(?<=N{{{}}})[^N].*?$'
    pattern = pattern.format(gapSize, gapSize, gapSize, gapSize)
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, s):
        #yield match.span()
        yield match

for match in foo(s, 10):
    print match.span(), match.group()

'''
>>> 
(0, 5) NAANA
(15, 24) BBBBNNNCC
(34, 39) DDDDN
>>>
'''
```

---

So if you think about it a bit you see that the beginning of a *gap* is the end of a *non-gap* and vis-versa.  So with a simple regex: iterate over the gaps, add logic to the loop to keep track of the *non-gap* spans, and `yield` the spans.  (my placeholder variable names could probably be improved)

```
s = 'NAANANNNNNNNNNNBBBBNNNCCNNNNNNNNNNDDDDN'
def bar(s, n):
    '''Yields the span of non-gap items in s or
       immediately raises StopIteration if gaps are not present.
    '''
    gap = r'N{{{},}}'.format(n)
    # initialize the placeholders
    previous_start = 0
    end = len(s)
    for match in re.finditer(gap, s):
        start, end = match.span()
        if start == 0:
            previous_start = end
            continue
        end = start
        yield previous_start, end
        previous_start = match.end()
    if end != len(s):
        yield previous_start, len(s)
```

Usage

```
for start, end in bar(s, 4):
    print (start, end), s[start:end]

'''
>>>
(0, 5) NAANA
(15, 24) BBBBNNNCC
(34, 39) DDDDN
>>>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought about regexes to directly match the wanted blocks, but nothing good came to mind. I think it's better to keep finding the gaps and simply use the gap coordinates to get the good block coordinates. I mean, they're basically the same, right? Gap stops are block starts and gap starts are block stops.

```
def get_block_coordinates(sequence, gapSize=25):
    gapPattern = "N{"+str(gapSize)+",}"
    p = re.compile(gapPattern)
    m = p.finditer(sequence)
    prevStop = 0
    for gap in m:
        start,stop = gap.span()
        if start:
            yield(prevStop,start)
        prevStop = stop
    if prevStop < len(sequence):
        yield(prevStop,len(sequence))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like:

```
gapPattern = "(N{"+str(gapSize)+",})"
p = re.compile(gapPattern)
i = 0
for s in re.split(p, sequence):
    if not re.match(p, s):
        yield i
    i += len(s)
```

And that'll generate a sequence of offsets to substrings that aren't `gap_size` `"N"` characters as per the [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.split) function.

Comment: Thanks Misandrist, but I only want the coordinates of the matched parts, not the actual split sequences itself. Also, I'd be very interested in how to solve it with a regex

Comment: If you split them with re.split and a match group, you can keep track of the position by using the lengths of the sequences split returns.